# Recorded Media file data is unreadable on Android11 pixel 3

Tags: android

recording media file in Pixel 3(Android11) when stop recorder , error log is

```
    E/MPEG4Writer: Stop() called but track is not started or stopped.

    but file is recorded but no exception in stop recording and after that when trying to read file using CheapAAc file using library https://github.com/Semantive/waveform-android
    giving error

    java.io.IOException: Went over by 7 bytes

    E/Utils: did not find channel-count and/or sample-rate
    E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.gralloc.disable_ahardware_buffer"
```

Comment: paste your code here

Comment: Have you solved it?